# set a background of disabled button?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, background

I need to set the background of disabled button.

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{
     Button1.IsEnabled = false;
     var brush = new ImageBrush();
     brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/AERO.png"));
     Button1.Background = brush;
}
```

If I do that, I will have disabled button without any background. 
I was looking for answer all morning and I didn't get what I want.
I found how to set background of disabled button in XAML but not in C#.

Comment: `I found how to set background of disabled button in XAML but not in C#` - UI elements are managed in XAML in WPF, together with data binding. You're not supposed to manipulate UI elements properties from procedural code.

Comment: So how can I change the background of my button when the program works?

Comment: @ŁukaszZimoń Define a custom `Style` in your app for the `Button` and if your basing it on the default template, remove the `ControlTemplate` `Trigger` for `Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"`

Comment: But I have windows Phone 7 App.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly but you can do it like my following code:

**XMAL Code**

```
<Button Name="button1"  Click="button1_Click" >
    <Image Name="btndisbackground" Visibility="Hidden" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="D:\1.jpg" Stretch="Fill"/>
</Button>
```

**button Code**

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    button1.IsEnabled = flase;
    btndisbackground.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the OP's question "I need to set the background of disabled button.", rather it shows how to programmatically disable the button.  I'm rather curious how the `btndisbackground.Visibility = Visibility.Visisble` branch will every get executed (a disabled button won't be raising `click` events!)

Comment: @STLDeveloper:`I'm rather curious how the btndisbackground.Visibility = Visibility.Visisble branch will every get executed (a disabled button won't be raising click events!)` this is a funny mistake :)) ,he want change button background when disabled

Comment: I have few buttons and every button must posses random image. For this reason I set the background button in the button Code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse the order your do things. Make setting the enabled state of the button the last thing you do:

```
private void Button1_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)    
{
     var brush = new ImageBrush();
     brush.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Images/AERO.png"));
     Button1.Background = brush;
     Button1.IsEnabled = false;
}
```

This will update the background image and *then* disable the button.